# How do I prove that $\lim_{z\to i} z^2=-1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

How do I prove the following limit using the limit definition? $$\lim_{z\to i} z^2=-1$$
Using the limit definition
  $$|z^2+1|<\epsilon, \;\text{whenever} 0<|z-i|<\delta$$
so I factor out to get that 
  $$|z^2+1|=|z+i||z-i|<\epsilon$$
 which means that if I am able to bound 
  $$|z+i|<K \tag{1}$$
then I can say that 
  $$|z-i||z+i|<K|z-i|<\epsilon \tag{2}$$
 and from there I could proceed to proving the limit, the only problem is that I do not know how to go from $(1)$ to $(2)$ using complex numbers. How could I prove this limit?

Comment: Your missing step is $|z+i|<K$, which is easy to achieve when $z$ is bounded.

Comment: To prove (1): use the triangle inequality on $|z+i | = |z-i+2i|$, or simplier, by using Yvea argument... To go from (1) to (2) just use that $|ab|=|a||b|$ even for complex numbers (both usual real/imaginary part splitting and polar coordinates work)

Answer (score 2):

By taking $0<\delta<\min\left\{1,\frac{\epsilon}3\right\}$ we get
\begin{align*}
|z^2+1|&=|z+i||z-i|\\
&\le\left(|z-i|+|2i|\right)|z-i|\qquad\text{from the triangular inequality}\\
&<(\delta +2)\delta\\
&<3\cdot\frac{\epsilon}3
\end{align*}
provided $|z-i|<\delta$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\delta = \min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{3}\}$, then
$$
0<|z-i|<1
$$
and so
$$
|z|-1<1
$$
by triangle inequality. Thus,
$$
|z+i|\le |z|+1< 3
$$
by triangle inequality again.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a neighborhood of radius $R$ around $i.$ Then $$|z^2+2|=|z+i||z-i|\le (|z-i|+|2i|)|z-i)\le (R+2)|z-i|.$$